How Do I make my sliding login/register page display the correct container
I Basically copied one of those sliding login/register pages, customized the CSS a bit and now I started doing backend for my project, I got to the part where I want to redirect users to register, but it opens the login form by default, then when they press sign up it slides over, is there a way of making the page do the animation on its own so when users click on register they don't have to click on sign up for it to slide over?
<div class="container" id="main">
        <div class="sign-up" id= "register-panel">
            <form action="Php/register_form.php" method="post">
                <h1>Create Account</h1>
                <p>or use your email for registration</p>
                <input type="text" name="txt" placeholder="Name" required="">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
                <input type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="Password" required="">
                <input type="number" class="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" inputmode="numeric" required="">
                <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>

                <?php
                session_start();
                $register_error = isset($_SESSION['register_error']) ? $_SESSION['register_error'] : '';
                if ($register_error != '') {
                    echo '<p style="color: crimson;font-size:10px;font-weight:Bold;padding-bottom:10px">' . $register_error . '</p>';
                    // Clear the error message after displaying
                    $_SESSION['register_error'] = '';
                }
                ?>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-in" id = "login-panel">
            <form action="Php/login_form.php" method="post">
                <h1>Sign In</h1>
                <p>or use your account</p>
                <input type="text" name="txt" placeholder="Name" required="">
                <input type="password" name="pswd" placeholder="Password" required="">
                <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
                
                <?php
                $login_error = isset($_SESSION['login_error']) ? $_SESSION['login_error'] : '';
                if ($login_error != '') {
                    echo '<p style="color: crimson;font-size:24px;font-weight:Bold">' . $login_error . '</p>';
                    // Clear the error message after displaying
                    $_SESSION['login_error'] = '';
                }
                ?>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay-container">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="overlay-left">
                    <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
                    <p>To stay connected with us, please login with your personal info</p>
                    <button id="signIn" data-panel = "login">Sign In</button>
                </div>
                <div class="overlay-right">
                    <h1>Hello Friend!</h1>
                    <p>Enter your personal details and start your journey with us</p>
                    <button id="signUp" data-panel = "register">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*<=================>Login Page<================>*/

body{
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #f6f5f7;
    font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 10%;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 768px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
    background: #ffff;
    border-radius: 25% 3%;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
                0 10px 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}

.sign-up, .sign-in{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
    will-change: transform;
}

.sign-up{
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sign-in{
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
}

form{
    background: #ffff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 50px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

h1{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

p{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    margin: 15px 0 20px;
}

input{
    background: #eee;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    margin: 8px 15px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

a{
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

button{
    color: #fff;
    background: #ff4b2b;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 55px;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ff4b2b;
    outline: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input.phone::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input.phone::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

button:active{
    transform: scale(0.90);
}

#signIn, #signUp{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #ffff
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-in{
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up{
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 5;
}

.overlay-container{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.7s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay{
    position: relative;
    color: #ffff;
    background: #ff416c;
    left: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#ff4b28,#ff228c);
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay{
    transform: translateX(50%);
}

.overlay-left, .overlay-right{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-left{
    transform: translateX(-20%);
}

.overlay-right{
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-left{
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-right{
    transform: translateX(20%);
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
    const signInButton = document.getElementById('signIn');
    const main = document.getElementById('main');

    signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        main.classList.add('right-panel-active');
    });
    signInButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        main.classList.remove('right-panel-active');
    });
});

I tried adding ?panel=register to the url to load the register panel by default and it didn't work

Where does the "sliding" happen? Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code, including the javascript and the rendered html.

@mykaf How do I add my code so it's formatted correctly, its not letting me do it, the sliding is happening with CSS transitions and JS onclick function
edit: Done

"but it opens the login form by default, then when they press sign up it slides over, How do I fix this? " What are you expecting it to do instead?

@mykaf I want to see if there's a way to open the page with the container already slid to the side so If I want to redirect people to login, it takes them to the default page, if I want them to register it takes them to the page that has already done the transition, fixed the question for clarity

Use your php and the url to add right-panel-active class to the appropriate element.

just add this class .right-panel-active to div with id='main'  like so <div class="container right-panel-active " id="main"> and it will be set as default for sign up
